# Is there a way to enable scanning of ITF-14 barcodes programmatically on the Android Zebra TC520K?

Tags: android, jquery, webview, barcode-scanner

I am using Android studio for my android code and javascript/jquery for my javascript front end (webView).

Right now, I can enable it through DataWedge manually, but not programmatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a DataWedge API, SET_CONFIG (https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/7-4/guide/api/setconfig/) which is invoked by sending an Android Intent to the DataWedge service.  Are you able to send Intents from your app?  E.g. by exposing an addJavascriptInterface to your WebView front end.  If so, you can use the SET_CONFIG API to configure the I 2 of 5 symbology.

Comment: Thank you. That is actually what we ended up doing.